# Incrementing net name for group in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, eda

I want to make 50 copies of the block below, but I need incrementing numbers on each of the net labels (these will go to a connector). I do not want each block connected to the other blocks. It would also be nice if I could do the same with the AVD text label.

I've tried using design blocks, but I cannot figure out a variable net label naming convention.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think EAGLE's 'module' feature might help. You can create a module with this block and have multiple instances of it.

Answer (score 0):

If a circuit part is to be copied without all the wires being connected the labels must not be attached until after copying (right side in screenshot).

If the circuit part including the labels is copied the wires are connected with each other (left part of the screenshot).

[image: Eagle Screenshot]